# WSO2 API Manager filter JSON result

Tags: wso2

I am trying to filter JSON results coming from our main application in our WSO2 API Manager and to filter URL's in the results. I haven't tried anything specific. Any ideas?

Comment: How would one create a proxy service that filters all incoming and outgoing requests to filter out a URL that is in the payload?

Answer (score 0):

In Filter mediator use xpath to identify the certain messages/properties.check the url in the payload and filter..Check the [documenation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Filter+Mediator)

Comment: I think my question wasn't very clear. I am not trying to filter based on URL. What I am trying to do is, for example, if I have a service that returns a user object (in JSON format) that contains: name, email address, telephone number and address, I want to be able to page the entire userobject to functionality that removes just the email address by searching for an exact email address.

Comment: You can achieve this while editing the api configuration.(which is in deployment/server/synapse folder) In the response path,have a class mediator which does this mapping logic and keep that in the response path/outsequence

Comment: Hi Ratha, I figured that would be the way to go about it. I have been trying to write an xslt file that would be used in the outsequence of all API definitions that would filter out any occurence of the phrase/url i am trying to filter out. However, my file is not getting detected and I get a null exception.

Comment: You have to use XSLT mediator in your outsequence,Store the xslt script in registry and point that from mediator. Do all changes from the sourceview(using management conosle) or open the apiconf in texteditor and edit. After finishing it save and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ratha, I really appreciate it. Is there documentation showing how to save the script to the registry? (is it just a matter of saving to the correct folder? or is it a special store?)

Comment: You need to use registry browser..go to management console(9443/carbon)What you do exactly in ESB, here also you can use/define mediation logics)

Comment: Hi Ratha, any live examples of this I can use? I am still struggling to get this to work.